# Refresh JTable after executing SQL UPDATE statement

Tags: java, mysql, swing, refresh

I created a JTable and defined MyTableModel in order to populate this table from MySQL DB. However, the problem is that when I execute UPDATE statement, then an additional row is included in JTable (but not in MySQL DB).

How should I update my code to be able to properly update JTable without re-opening the application? (I'm using fireTableChanged(null))

```
 public class QueryTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
      Vector cache;
      int colCount;
      String[] headers;

      String db;
      String dbHost;
      String dbLogin;
      String dbPassw;     
      Statement statement;

      public QueryTableModel() {
        cache = new Vector();
      }

      public String getColumnName(int i) {
        return headers[i];
      }

      public int getColumnCount() {
        return colCount;
      }

      public int getRowCount() {
        return cache.size();
      }

      public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
        return ((String[]) cache.elementAt(row))[col];
      }

      public Connection getConnection()
                throws Exception {
            String dbURL = "";
            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("Cannot find the MySQL JDBC driver. ");
                throw (e);
            }
            try {
                dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://" + dbHost + "/" + db;
                // WINDOWS
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL,dbLogin,dbPassw);
                // LINUX
                // Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
                return con;
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("No connection with " + dbURL);
                throw (e);
            }
        }

      public void setQuery(String query) {
        cache = new Vector();
        try {
          // Execute the query and store the result set and its metadata
          Connection con = getConnection();
          Statement statement = con.createStatement();
          ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(query);
          ResultSetMetaData meta = rs.getMetaData();
          colCount = meta.getColumnCount();

          // Rebuild the headers array with the new column names
          headers = new String[colCount];
          for (int h = 1; h <= colCount; h++) {
            headers[h - 1] = meta.getColumnName(h);
          }

          while (rs.next()) {
            String[] record = new String[colCount];
            for (int i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
              record[i] = rs.getString(i + 1);
            }
            cache.addElement(record);
          }
          fireTableChanged(null);

          rs.close();
          if (con.getAutoCommit() != false) {
            con.close();
          }

        } catch (Exception e) {
          cache = new Vector(); // blank it out and keep going.
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }

      public void setQueryUpdate(String[] data, String q) {
        try {
          Connection con = getConnection();
          Statement statement = con.createStatement();
          int rs = statement.executeUpdate(q);
          String[] record = new String[data.length];
          for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            record[i] = data[i];
          }
          cache.addElement(record);
          fireTableChanged(null);
          if (con.getAutoCommit() != false) {
            con.close();
          }
        } catch (Exception e) {
          cache = new Vector(); // blank it out and keep going.
          System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
      }

    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you are doing, but updates should be made directly to the TableModel, not the Vector holding the data. The TableModel will then invoke the proper fireXXX method. You should not be invoking these methods directly.

Comment: I've just edited my post by including the whole code of QueryTableModel. SO, setQueryUpdate is just a part of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I see what you’re trying here.  You need to call:

```
fireTableDataChanged();
```

If you call `fireTableChange(null)` all the listeners will be called with Event equal to null.  Depending on the implementation it will a) throw a NPE or b) do nothing.  The `fireTableDataChanged();` tells listeners that data has changed and to update accordingly.

Comment: Please look at the whole code of QueryTableModel. I wrote it based on different examples that I found in Google. It works well excluding Update.

Comment: Probably, I just need to delete from 'cache' the current row that needs to be updated, and then add the new one. But it does not seem to be the best solution.

Comment: @Klausos Klausos With this approach that's probably what needs to be done.

Comment: Ok,thanks. I solved the problem by including "       cache.removeElementAt(index); cache.insertElementAt(record, index);" into 'setQueryUpdate'.